# Finding if a Rectangle Touches a Line

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, intersection

I have a class called Rectangle which consists of two pairs of integers, meant to represent XY coordinates for the top left and bottom right corners of a rectangle. I also have a class called Quadrant, which consists of X values for the leftmost, middle, and rightmost points on a square area (leftX, midX, and rightX respectively), and also similar values for the top, middle, and bottom on the Y plane (botY, midY, topY). I want to determine if the given rectangle touches the middle sections of either the x or y planes of the given quadrant. Right now this is my code for doing so:

```
boolean isIntersect(Rectangle rect, Quadrant node)
    {

        boolean xOver = false;
        boolean yOver = false;




        if((rect.bottomRight.x >=node.midX && rect.topLeft.x <= node.midX) ||
            (rect.bottomRight.x <=node.midX && rect.topLeft.x >= node.midX))

        {
            xOver = true;
        }

        if((rect.bottomRight.y <= node.midY && rect.topLeft.y >= node.midY) ||
            (rect.bottomRight.y >= node.midY && rect.topLeft.y <= node.midY))
        {

            yOver = true;
        }



        if (yOver || xOver == true)

        {
            System.out.println("intersection found");
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.println("no intersection found");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

After testing this code with randomized rectangles, I know that there are a lot of cases this does not cover, but I'm not sure which ones or how to address them. Does anyone know of a better, more thorough algorithm?

Comment: So the Rectangles are axe-paralell?

Comment: You might consider posting this on codereview.stackexchange.com after you think you've got most (or all) of your corner-cases :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is great. Here it is implemented a little cleaner; you're working with a lot more booleans than you need to be.

```
boolean isIntersect(Rectangle rect, Quadrant node)
{
    return (rect.bottomRight.x >=node.midX && rect.topLeft.x <= node.midX)
        || (rect.bottomRight.y <= node.midY && rect.topLeft.y >= node.midY)
}
```

In your code, it looks like you're also testing the case where, for the rectangle,

```
bottomRight.x <= node.midX && topLeft.x >= node.midX
```

meaning that the bottom right would really be the bottom left corner of your rectangle and the top left would really the top right. (There is a similar case in your test of the y-values.)

When creating your rectangles, do you do anything to ensure that the coordinates given for the bottom right and top left corners really represent those corners?